# Hash returns negative value

Tags: c++, hash

Why does it return negative? And how do I make the return value positive?

KeyInput: ABCD123

```
for(int a=0; a<keyInput.length(); a++){
        key = ((key << 5)+key)^keyInput[a];
    }

return key;
```

Comment: As chris said, is key a signed type?  Probably a bad idea.

Comment: If top bit gets set it becomes negative... When you are manipulating bits you don't want the top bit to have special significance

Comment: `unsigned int` the `key`

Answer (score 2):

Make 'key' an unsigned type, such as '`unsigned int`'.

The reason it turns negative is because for signed types, the high bit indicates the sign. Once the hash was bigger than 0x7FFFFFFF, the sign bit becomes '1' and the value goes negative. Unsigned types don't use a sign bit. Values that are too big continue to remain positive.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `key` as unsigned long integer should do the trick.